# preview image before upload to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to programming and not so good at programming, 
I want to create a from with person name, preview image and store in database(MYSQL)

so far I can save to database of person name, file name, file type, and size.OK.
image store to folder is also.OK.

The problem is i cant preview image before the user click on upload
another problem I dont want to show array of all the upload only my current upload.

### Database: `dbtuts`

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tbl_uploads`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_uploads` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tbl_uploads`
--

INSERT INTO `tbl_uploads` (`id`, `name`, `file`, `type`, `size`) VALUES
(1, '', '70455-(r)11d.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 19),
(2, '', '77190-3d-glass-green-effect.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 249),
(3, '', '85477-123.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 19),
(4, '', '12982-123.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 19),
(5, '', '35705-123.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 19),
(6, '', '48313-123.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 19),
(7, '', '28810-123.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 19),
(8, '', '67467-123.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 19),
(9, 'dddd', '80982-123.jpg', 'image/jpeg', 19);
```

dbconfig.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "dbtuts";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die('cannot connect to the server'); 
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('database selection problem');
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>File Uploading With PHP and MySql</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<label>File Uploading With PHP and MySql(Test)</label>
</div>
<div id="body">
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
    </form>
    <br /><br />
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['success']))
    {
        include 'view.php';
        ?>
        <label>File Uploaded Successfully... </label> 

<!--         <a href="view.php">click here to view file.</a> -->
        <?php
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['fail']))
    {
        ?>
        <label>Problem While File Uploading !</label>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <label>Try to upload any files(PDF, DOC, EXE, VIDEO, MP3, ZIP,etc...)</label>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

view.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>File Uploading With PHP and MySql</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<label>File Uploading With PHP and MySql</label>
</div>
<div id="body">
    <table width="80%" border="1">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4">your uploads...<label><a href="index.php">upload new files...</a></label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>File Name</td>
    <td>File Type</td>
    <td>File Size(KB)</td>
    <td>View</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads";
    $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['file'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>
        <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">view file</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB

    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(name,file,type,size) VALUES('$name','$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('successfully uploaded');
        window.location.href='index.php?success';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MYSQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

Comment: (...And insecure...)